# How to specify PDO driver-specific connection options in config.ini file?

Tags: php, pdo, config

My typical PDO connection is as follows.  How can I set the driver-specific connection options (i.e. `\PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE=>\PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION`) in the config.ini file without converting these option constants to their integer values?

```
<?php

$config=parse_ini_file(__DIR__.'/../config.ini', true, INI_SCANNER_TYPED);
$db = $config['mysql'];
$conn=new \PDO(
    "mysql:host={$db['host']};port={$db['port']};dbname={$db['dbname']};charset={$db['charset']}",
    $db['username'],
    $db['password'],
    [
        \PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES=>false,
        \PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_USE_BUFFERED_QUERY=>true,
        \PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE=>\PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
        \PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE=>\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC
    ]
);
```

config.ini

```
[mysql]
host        =   localhost
port        =   3306
charset     =   utf8mb4
dbname      =   myDatabase
username    =   myUsername
password    =   myPassword
;options[PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES]         =   false
;options[PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_USE_BUFFERED_QUERY] =   true
;options[PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE]                  =   PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION
;options[PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE]       =   PDO::FETCH_ASSOC
```

Comment: you can't - hence `.ini` is string and PDO expects integer, for the index and the value. `.ini` files may even pose a security risk, in case the web-server serves them.

Comment: @MartinZeitler  Okay, thanks, if I elect to include in `config.ini`, I will use the constants and document my `config.ini` file as appropriate.  Off topic, if `config.ini` is located in a non-public location, why do you say it poses a security risk?

Comment: I've wrote `may pose` not `poses` ...while providing the condition, too. it's just the type of file one does not want to serve (preferably dictated by global configuration). a `config.php` might be rather suitable, so that name-space `\PDO` could be resolved; else you'd need a small driver, which converts string to integer, when parsing the `.ini` file.

Comment: The security risk is mitigated if you put the config.ini outside the http document root, so the web server cannot serve it up if someone tries to load it by direct URL. In fact, it's a good idea to put all PHP code outside the document root, except for your framework's front controller.

Answer (score 1):

Per Martin's comments, this is what I ended up doing:

```
[mysql]
host        =   localhost
port        =   3306
charset     =   utf8mb4
dbname      =   myDatabase
username    =   myUsername
password    =   myPassword
options[20]     =   false   ;PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES
options[1000]   =   true    ;PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_USE_BUFFERED_QUERY
options[3]      =   2       ;PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION
options[19]     =   2       ;PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC
```